# Write to a file in PHP and then download it

Tags: php

I am working on a project where I get a file stream and write this file to the servers local disk.

I then want PHP to download it but instead it just dumps out the data of the file to the page.

Below is how I am writing the file and trying to tell PHP to download it

```
$settingsManager = new SettingsManager();
$this->tempWriteLocation = $settingsManager->getSpecificSetting("hddFileWriterLocation");
$downloadUrl = $settingsManager->getSpecificSetting("tempFileUrlDownload") . "/$this->tempFileName";
if (!$this->checkIfDirectoryExists())
{
     throw new Exception("Failed to create temp write directory: $this->tempWriteLocation");
}
$filePathAndName = "$this->tempWriteLocation\\$this->tempFileName";
$fh = fopen($filePathAndName, "w");
if (!$fh)
{
     throw new Exception("Failed to open file handle for: $filePathAndName. " . error_get_last());
}
fwrite($fh, $this->fileData);
fclose($fh);
//return $downloadUrl;
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: audio/wav');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filePathAndName));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePathAndName));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filePathAndName);
```

When the above code being run, I get the following output (only a snippet)

> RIFF\tWAVELIST2INFOISFT%Aculab Media System Server V2.3.4b11fmt
>   @@fact�sdata�sUU������UUUUUU�UUU��U���UU��UUU�UUUU���UU���UU�����UU

Just so you know the diamonds are actual output I get back, not anything wrong with Stack Overflow displaying something properly.

I've tried setting the content-type to be force-download but doesn't make any difference.

Comment: This part generates a fatal error:  `$this->tempWriteLocation\\$this->tempFileName`  and a few other like this unless this is a class (which you forgot to include!)

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting? Can it be you output _something_ (it may be just whitespace) _before_ you do your first `header()` call?

Comment: It is part of a class. All of the code is working apart from the download. You can see that from snippet of the output where it has RIFF WAVE. I do have error reporting turned on and set to display which there aren't any.

Comment: `ob_clean();
flush();` <--- what's this for?

Comment: To be honest not sure. There were a couple of examples i found on Google were doing this so assumed to be needed

Comment: No there's not. I'll try adding one and try removing the ob stuff and see if either works

Comment: I'vd tried adding the ob_start and removing the ob_* completely but neither makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

Try this header:

```
header('Content-type: audio/x-wav', true);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=wav-filename.wav');
```

and see if this works. From what I see you have you code formation setup correctly. Fixing the headers should download the file automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but it still giving me the output to the screen of the file instead of downloading